# Chrome Extension runs only once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, load, phishing

I just started creating Chrome Extensions and I wanted to write one which deletes messages on the site Dota-Trade.com which include phishing links.

I got everything working except that the script only removes the messages if I press <kbd>F5</kbd>. If I navigate through the site and click on 'Messages' just nothing happens. How can I change this?

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "Dota-Trade.com Fake Link Blocker",
  "version": "2",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "description": "Deletes content which contain urls except official ones. By Trojan.",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": [
        "http://dota-trade.com/messages"],
        "js": ["main.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end",
        "all_frames": true
    }
  ]
}
```

And my main.js

```
function remove(){
  var div = document.getElementById("threads");
  var messages = div.getElementsByClassName("message te clear");

  for (var i=0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    rp = messages[i].getElementsByClassName("rp");

    messagetextobj = rp[0].getElementsByClassName("text");
    var messagetext = messagetextobj[0].textContent;

    if (messagetext.indexOf(".com/profiles") > -1 && messagetext.indexOf("steamcommunity.com") == -1) {
      div.removeChild(messages[i]);
    };
  }

  setTimeout(function(){remove();},500);
}

remove();
```

Comment: Does clicking on `Messages` redirects to `http://dota-trade.com/messages` or you are already on it?

Comment: It redirects to http://dota-trade.com/messages

Comment: and then if you press `5`, the script works?

Comment: Oh my god Im so dump. I meant f5.

Comment: @Trojan I've edited formatting of your question a bit.

Comment: @Trojan : Are you expecting that `remove()` works after every `0.5 seconds` ???

Comment: thank you sir, xan. 
@ParagGangil no, as I said this is my first js-script. I just want all of the containers to be deleted. :)

Comment: no solution @ParagGangil ?

Comment: @Trojan : Since, I have not been to `dota-trade`, I don't know about its structure. And since your script works on `reload`, thus there is no problem in your script. In your `manifest`, you have  `"matches": ["http://dota-trade.com/messages"],`, try changing it with `"http://dota-trade.com/messages/*"`. Also, try adding some `console.log('1')` in your script to see how much your script has executed.